# Asking a debate participant for consent to use their audio recordings, video recordings, debate notes etc for educational purposes,

Tags: single-word-requests

If I'm asking a debate participant for consent to use their audio recordings, video recordings, debate notes etc for educational purposes, what word or expression would cover all the above? Can I use the expression "documentation"?

Comment: I suspect that "documentation" would be assumed to only cover the "printed" notes.

Comment: *Will you grant us permission to use your **contribution** to the debate for educational purposes?* Where I might consider pluralising ***contributions*** purely in order to more strongly imply ***everything*** (including preparatory notes and debate-time jottings if available, as well as all recorded material).

Comment: This is probably a fairly complex legal question of copyright law.

Answer (score -1):

I think just the term "recordings" alone fits well here. Written notes are a type of recording, and I'm pretty sure most people would agree that they fit under that umbrella term.

Comment: Not convinced this is true. A transcript or notes made at the time of the talk might arguably be considered "recordings", although they're not what someone would first think of by the word; but a speaker's notes made prior to the debate (of points to cover, things to say, references, etc) would not, and in either case it is better to obtain explicit consent rather than argue later about what is meant. So "notes and recordings" is better.